# Why fastecdsa and secp256k1 produce different signatures?

Tags: python, cryptography, ecdsa

`fastecdsa` Python package supports secp256k1 curve. Public keys produced from the same private key with `fastecdsa` using secp256k1 and `secp256k1` package match. However, signatures don't match:

```
import secp256k1
pk = secp256k1.PrivateKey(k.secret_exponent)
raw_sig = pk.ecdsa_sign(message, digest=blake2b_32)
sig = pk.ecdsa_serialize_compact(raw_sig)
print("secp lib sig: " + base58_encode(sig, b"spsig").decode())

import fastecdsa
from fastecdsa.ecdsa import sign
from fastecdsa.encoding.util import bytes_to_int, int_to_bytes
r, s = sign(msg=message, d=bytes_to_int(k.secret_exponent), curve=fastecdsa.curve.secp256k1, hashfunc=blake2b_32)
fsig = int_to_bytes(r) + int_to_bytes(s)
print(base58_encode(fsig, b"spsig"))
```

`k.secret_exponent` is from Key class of `pytezos` package, but it is not important in this context, it is just 32 bytes. Main thing is that it is the same in calls of `secp256k1` and `fastecdsa`.

`base58_encode` is also from `pytezos`, I could just output bytes with `hex()` with the same result.

Why would signatures be different if curves are the same?

```
fastecdsa              1.7.3
secp256k1              0.13.2
```

Comment: Do you have example of the signatures in in base 64 or hex for those without the correct package setup?

Comment: Sure.

secp256k1: 5d6728ce3cdcfcf725aca108985b34ef40f1d316cfa87d54b239a4ca0f3a4dc24117f3bcd21552c1cfda32d40733b664de7090ea51e6ee4865b45507ee09018c

fastecdsa: b5a447731f7faba35e02b262605f039504539197cd1464bb922bbe4395abcc1d49019464f9f2b649fcd98e2c60cfc3dabc913fa1a3319894bd1b0824966b0d23

I have made some additional experiment and found that though signatures are completely different, signature produced by one library will be verified with another library just fine. Public key would also be extracted correctly.

Comment: @DimaA6_ABC is it related to the k value during signature that acts as a non-deterministic element during the ECDSA process?

Comment: DSA and ECDSA have random components, so signatures over the same data are supposed to be different. There is a variant of these that replaces the random component with a deterministic one, getting rid of the "Sony foot-gun" problem, but I'm not sure either of those libraries supports this variant.

Comment: @James Reinstate Monica Polk both libraries have deterministic nonce. If you generate signature several times with the same library, signature will be the same. However, it might be that deterministic nonce algorithms are different in different libraries.

Comment: @DimaA6_ABC: Thank you for checking that out.